# How to set Tokenizer() function of Spark NLP to split tokens by comma?

Tags: pyspark, tokenize, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I'm building a pipeline in Spark NLP (version 3.2.1) to create Tokens from a string column that contains searched words by words separated by comma.

```
documentAssemblerteste = DocumentAssembler() \
.setInputCol("searched_terms") \
.setOutputCol("searched_terms_doc")\
.setCleanupMode("shrink_full")

regexTokenizerteste = Tokenizer() \
.setInputCols(["str_search_term_doc"]) \
.setSplitChars([","])\
.setOutputCol("token")

finisherteste = Finisher()\
.setInputCols("token")\
.setOutputCols("token_final")

pipeline = Pipeline().setStages([
documentAssemblerteste,    
regexTokenizerteste,
finisherteste
])
```

But it gives me the wrong expected output. For an example, a row that contains these searched words

```
"pizza, hot dog, supermarket"
```

returns:

```
['pizza', 'hot', 'dog', 'supermarket']
```

But i want it to ignore spaces and gives me the following output:

```
['pizza', 'hot dog', 'supermarket']
```

How can i achieve this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark ML provides a [regexTokenizer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer.html) class. To set the regex pattern, use the `setPattern()` method or pass the pattern as a keyword argument to the constructor.

Just be aware that it uses Java dialect of regex, as mentioned [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer.html#pyspark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer.pattern).